# How are XML namespaces validated on W3C's validator?

Tags: xml, svg, xml-namespaces

I have two files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   width="210mm"
   height="297mm"
   viewBox="0 0 210 297"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg5"   
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   inkscape:version="1.1.1 (c3084ef, 2021-09-22)"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
</svg>
```

This one validates fine on W3C validator. But once I edit the namespace, i.e. URI in `xmlns:inkscape` it starts to fail:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   width="210mm"
   height="297mm"
   viewBox="0 0 210 297"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg5"   
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/ABC"
   inkscape:version="1.1.1 (c3084ef, 2021-09-22)"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
</svg>
```

It gives me this error:

> Line 10, Column 38: Attribute version from namespace http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/ABC not allowed on SVG element svg at this point.

I use https://validator.w3.org/ for validating it. I have to upload these as `.svg` files. I can not paste it into direct input, as it doesn't detect the format and there is no such selection in the manual choice (`SVG 1.1 + URL + HTML + MathML 3.0` is detected in file upload).

What kind of black magic is going on here? I thought those URIs are pretty free-form, but it looks like W3C validator pulls some sort of schema from somewhere even if nothing is specified.

I also noticed that I can rename the namespace to something else and it all works as long as I keep the same URI.

How does validation of namespaces work? I'm just trying to add my custom namespace to my SVG files...

Comment: What validator did you use exactly? https://validator.w3.org/ is pretty happy with both inputs.

Comment: Don't tell us something fails without telling us how it fails. What's the error message?

Comment: Thanks, guys! I added the details. You're right validator.w3.org is happy with the input if you use direct-input, because then it thinks it's just an XML file and not an SVG. Uploading these as files gives an error for one, but not for the other.

Answer (score 2):

The "magic" can be found by looking at the [sources](https://github.com/w3c/markup-validator):

1. All files that do not have a `DOCTYPE` declaration, and all files that have  a `.svg` extension are checked [by delegation](https://github.com/w3c/markup-validator/blob/2e94f8f7f387a8e89cd5d9464972b7300db191b6/httpd/cgi-bin/check#L623) to the [Nu Html Checker](https://github.com/validator/validator/):

   > ```
   > # we send doctypeless SVG, or any doctypeless XML document with multiple
   > # namespaces found, to a different engine. WARNING this is experimental.
   > ```
2. As you found, this validator [identifies](https://github.com/validator/validator/blob/10f5050815dbdc58f51600ba3bd9c11ff942559a/resources/presets.txt#L5) the file as `SVG 1.1 + URL + HTML + MathML 3.0`. These files are checked via a Relax NG scheme called `svg-xhtml5-rdf-mathml.rnc`. And that file explicitely [checks against the inkscape namespace](https://github.com/validator/validator/blob/10f5050815dbdc58f51600ba3bd9c11ff942559a/schema/.drivers/svg-xhtml5-rdf-mathml.rnc#L9).